# iPhone MonoTouch - Get Version of Bundle

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

In MonoTouch, how can we get the version of the bundle currently running?

My closest guess is somewhere in :

```
NSBundle.MainBundle.ObjectForInfoDictionary
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use the following code to get the current version of the bundle:

```
NSBundle.MainBundle.ObjectForInfoDictionary("CFBundleVersion").ToString();
```

Comment: How to access `NSBundle` inside a `ContentPage`?