# How to get the app version from ContentPage?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I tried this: [iPhone MonoTouch - Get Version of Bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700136/iphone-monotouch-get-version-of-bundle)

```
NSBundle.MainBundle.ObjectForInfoDictionary("CFBundleVersion").ToString();
```

But this didn't work. As `NSBundle` can't be found.

How can I get the app version (iOS and Android) from ContentPage?

The code which i ended up with (thanks to Steven Thewissen):

PCL (shared code)

```
using System;
namespace MyApp.Interfaces
{
    public interface IApplicationVersion
    {
        string ApplicationsPublicVersion { get; set; }
        string ApplicationsPrivateVersion { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Android

```
using System;
using MyApp.Droid.Helpers;
using MyApp.Interfaces;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(ApplicationVersion))]
namespace MyApp.Droid.Helpers
{
    public class ApplicationVersion : IApplicationVersion
    {
        public string ApplicationsPublicVersion { get; set; }
        public string ApplicationsPrivateVersion { get; set; }

        public ApplicationVersion()
        {
            var context = Android.App.Application.Context;
            var info = context.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(context.PackageName, 0);

            ApplicationsPublicVersion = info.VersionName;
            ApplicationsPrivateVersion = info.VersionCode.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

iOS

```
using System;
using MyApp.Interfaces;
using MyApp.iOS.Helpers;
using Foundation;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(ApplicationVersion))]
namespace MyApp.iOS.Helpers
{
    public class ApplicationVersion : IApplicationVersion
    {
        public string ApplicationsPublicVersion { get; set; }
        public string ApplicationsPrivateVersion { get; set; }

        public ApplicationVersion()
        {
            ApplicationsPublicVersion = NSBundle.MainBundle.InfoDictionary[new NSString("CFBundleShortVersionString")].ToString();
            ApplicationsPrivateVersion = NSBundle.MainBundle.InfoDictionary[new NSString("CFBundleVersion")].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this by implementing a Dependency Service. First you define an interface in your shared code:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public interface IAppVersionProvider
    {
        string AppVersion { get; }
    }
}
```

In each platform project you then implement the interface.

**iOS**

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(AppVersionProvider))]
namespace MyApp.iOS
{
    public class AppVersionProvider : IAppVersionProvider
    {
        public string AppVersion => NSBundle.MainBundle.InfoDictionary[new NSString("CFBundleVersion")].ToString();
    }
}
```

**Android**

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(AppVersionProvider))]
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    public class AppVersionProvider : IAppVersionProvider
    {
        public string AppVersion
        {
            get
            {
                var context = Android.App.Application.Context;
                var info = context.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(context.PackageName, 0);

                return $"{info.VersionName}.{info.VersionCode.ToString()}";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can then retrieve the version number from shared code through:

```
var version = DependencyService.Get<IAppVersionProvider>();
var versionString = version.AppVersion;
```

Comment: Working like a charm. I just had to use constructors instead of properties. Don't know why it didn't work with properties (i added it to my question). Thanks! :)

Comment: Where exact must I put this code in the android and ios project ? And where in the shared code ? I am a complete newbie in xamarin so I don't understand how to use this

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to use dependency services, you can just use the class `VersionTracking`.

The property `VersionTracking.CurrentVersion` will give you the Version you can set in your Android `properties` and your iOS `info.plist`.

This class is provided by `Xamarin.Essentials` and can give you a lot of informations. Please, check the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/version-tracking) for more informations.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** *listed incorrect nuget package, changes made below.*

You should in theory be able to use something like the below inside the OnStart(); method of your App.cs in your forms project.

```
    Context context = this.ApplicationContext;
    SupportFunctions.Version = context.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(context.PackageName, 0).VersionName;
```

However we use a plugin created by Mark Trinder called "Xam.Plugin.Version" which can be found on nuget<sup>1</sup> and on GitHub<sup>2</sup>. Once it's installed into your forms & native projects it's simply called as so:

```
using Version.Plugin;

private void SomeMethod()
{
     MyLabel.Text = CrossVersion.Current.Version;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> nuget package [Here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Version)

<sup>2</sup> Github [Here](https://github.com/mtrinder/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Version) :

Comment: I don't believe that NuGet has any such functionality in it. If it did I'd love to see a piece of code for it :)

Comment: This didn't work for me. "'Error: App.OnCreate()': no suitable method found to override"

Comment: @JedatKinports apologies I rushed posting that answer and cross referenced a few incorrect details, edit has been made.

Comment: @StevenThewissen Apologies Steven, you were right I cross referenced the wrong nuget package from one of our forms project. Updated the answer above with the correct one.